# TryParse to through multiple values

Tags: c#, casting

I have been using

```
 int.TryParse(_dtPOSettings.Rows[0]["PASID"].ToString(), out categoryID);
```

to get string value converted to int. This is working fine when PASID value is a single value.
Now I store multiple values in database as a ',' seperated list. When I get them back i'm splitting them and storing them to a string array. Now i want int.TryParse to take values of string array and convert them to int values and put them back to a int typed list.
But the out param does not support this. Please suggest on how to code this.

```
int.TryParse(PASIDValues[i].ToString(), out PASIDintValues[i]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop over the string array and tryParse each element; result of which goes into your list.

Comment: `"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

Simply declare a variable to hold value temporarily and if the parse is successful, assign value to array index

```
int temp = 0;

if(int.TryParse(PASIDValues[i].ToString(), out temp))
    PASIDintValues[i] = temp;
```

Comment: +1 - 1:58 ahead of me and the extra 'e' didn't make a difference. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to instantiate the full length of the values you plan to store as a result of your conversion, and use a temporary variable to get the value from `int.TryParse`.

```
int[] PASIDintValues = new int[PASIDValues.Count()];
for(int i = 0; i < PASIDValues.Count() - 1; i ++)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(PASIDValues[i].ToString(), out tmp))
        results[i] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a reference to a `List` element, but you can make one to an array element. Just make `PASIDintValues` an array instead of a list and it should work.

Comment: What overload of [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) takes an array as its `out` parameter?

Comment: @M.Babcock: You don't pass an array to `TryParse`, you pass a reference to an element: `int.TryParse(PASIDValues[i].ToString(), out PASIDintValues[i]);` where `PASIDintValues` is an `int[]`.